# Is the word "which" omitted before "enough"?

Tags: grammar

In *The Kissing Booth 2 (2020)*, Marco just performed a street song, asks Elle and Lee:

> Marco: What'd you think, Elle?
>
> Elle: Oh, you know, my opinion doesn't really matter. I'm sure you're
> impressed with **yourself enough** for the both of us.

Is the word "which" omitted before "enough"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"impressed with yourself" means that Marco thinks he has done well. "enough for both of us" means that Elle contribution is unnecessary. Together they mean that Elle thinks Marco is so impressed with himself that he won't take any notice of what Elle says.

The words "yourself" and "enough" are not really linked to each other, and adding "which" would not improve the sentence.